# Where to put Programming Language that is not in skills set on Resume, but on project portfolio?

Tags: resume

From [this question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/48751/is-it-ok-to-put-a-currently-learning-in-the-skills-section-of-a-cv), it seems that including skills you are currently learning into a resume is not a good idea.

However, if I am currently working on a project using programming language and framework that I am learning as I go, is there anywhere in my resume to write it down? Could I list them as technologies used on that particular project under my Work Experience?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It is quite common to put anything you have at least some experience using in the skills section.**

It doesn't imply you are an expert, and won't be understood as such.  Anyone reading your resume will understand that.  It is only used as a quick gauge of what things you have familiarity with.

So if you are still learning a tool or technology, but have at least gotten far enough that you have a project in progress with some significant code written, there is no problem with listing this as a skill.

If you want to communicate that you are an expert in something in your resume, you need to do more than list it as a skill: you need to detail your specific experience or areas of knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

The linked question is about somebody saying his skill is "close to nil". That indeed makes no sense in the skills section.

If you are proficient enough to do a project in it, I would assume it should go into your skills section.

Answer (score 0):

Always put everything relevant to the job for which you are applying in the "skills" section.  If you only have limited skill/use of it, put it down as "knowledge of..." but if it is in the body of your resume, it should **always** be in the skills section.